# Sometimes rounding number are not consistent

Tags: r

Please can you help to solve this issue:

```
round(30.5)
[1] 30 
round(31.5)
[1] 32
```

I want to get always 0.5s either up or down. Any solution

Comment: `floor` or `ceiling`?

Comment: I know them, it's a no sorry. We do not idea of numbers, but when we have 0.5s in data, I want to get always them either up or down

Comment: R uses rounding to even integer when tie

Comment: Rawr, can you re read the question and the comment please

Comment: creating your own function will help

Comment: may I have your function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is yet another instance of [R-FAQ 7.31 (link to the FAQ on your device)](http://127.0.0.1:23592/doc/manual/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) ...... [(link to the CRAN version)](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). If you always want floating point numbers that are displayed by `print.default` as x.5 to "round up" then you need to add a bit of "fuzz". I chose that amount of fuzz to be similar to the accuracy with which print.default usually displays numbers.

```
  >  round(30.5 +0.00000001)
[1] 31
```

To make this happen in a function:

```
> round.up <- function(x, digits=0) round(x+0.00000001, digits)
> round.up(30.5)
```

You might also ponder this:

```
> 31.5==31.50000000000000001
[1] TRUE
> 31.5==31.5000000000000001
[1] TRUE
> 31.5==31.500000000000001
[1] TRUE
> 31.5==31.50000000000001
[1] FALSE

>  31.50000000000001
[1] 31.5

> 31.50000001
[1] 31.5
> 31.50001
[1] 31.50001
```

Comment: Thanks, can you advise for round down

Comment: Chnage the the math operation to `'-'`

Answer (score 0):

A solution that does not need a print-format dependent offset:

To always round up, use

```
ceiling(x - 0.5)
```

To always round down, use

```
floor(x + 0.5)
```